# SSRS rdl Report Problem while rendering in MVC C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, c#-3.0

Any one who have solution, I had stack into the problem regarding the width of rdl report rendering using @Html.ReportViewer
in MVC C#. The width of RDL report is not fit to the parent div as red arrow is showing in the picture.

**I had written the below c# code for ReportViewer.**

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
viewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
viewer.ShowPrintButton = true;
viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ssrsUrl);
viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/RDL_Reports/SP_Product_Master_Report";
viewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
viewer.ShowExportControls = true;
viewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
viewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
viewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
ViewBag.ReportViewer = viewer;
```

**In HTML**
@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { id = "report" })

**Preview**

[After rendering rdl report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djcsc.png)

Any one have solution,
to fit the RDL report to the width of parent div size.
I mean to say that remove the gap between the RDL report and the parent div so that it can fit to the size of parent div.

**I had try many trick, But I failed.**